# How a JFrame can show an image depending of a result in the code?

Tags: java, jframe

as the title says, i want to show one of three images in a JFrame depending of a result in the code.

The code that determines the result is this:

Equilatero, Escaleno and Isosceles are the results.

```js
private void CActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
       double la,lb,lc;
       double a;
       double p;
       String t=null;
       
       la=Double.parseDouble(LA.getText());
       lb=Double.parseDouble(LB.getText());
       lc=Double.parseDouble(LC.getText());
       
      if (la==lb && la==lc){
        t=("Equilatero");
     }else if (la==lb || lb==lc || la==lc) {
        t=("Isósceles");  
     }else if (la!=lb || lb!=lc || la!=lc) {
        t=("Escaleno");    
     }
     if (lb+lc>la && la+lc>lb && la+lb>lc){
     a=Math.sqrt((la+lb+lc)*(-la+lb+lc)*(la-lb+lc)*(la+lb-lc)/16);
     p=la+lb+lc;
     //A.setText("El area del triangulo "+t+" es ("+a+").");
     A.setText("El triangulo "+t+" tiene un area de ("+a+") y un perimetro de ("+p+").");  
     } else {
     A.setText("Los valores ("+la+"), ("+lb+") y ("+lc+") no corresponden a los lados de un triangulo."); 
     }
    }
```

Comment: do you have the imageicons for each image already?

Comment: Code review item: your variable names are too short to be meaningful to anyone else who reads this. Names like `la`, `lb`, `lc`, `a`, etc. make your code very hard to understand.

Comment: Another review item: using variable names that start with capital letters does not follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) so unless `LA`, `LB`, etc are classes they should not start with a capital letter.

Comment: sorry, the meaning of the items are: la (side 1), lb (side 2), lc (side 3). The program determines the area and the type of a triangle so the item "a" is releated with the area, "p" is releated with the perimeter and "t" is the triangle type. Then my main problem is that I´m new on the language (java) and I really dont know anything about images in java

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a pain to set an image on a `JFrame`... what you could do instead that's much easier is create a `JLabel` or `JPanel` and set its image, and then add the `JLabel` or `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.

That being said, you could do a `switch` statement to figure out which type of triangle is the result:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JLabel label = new JLabel(); //or JPanel if that's what you prefer
ImageIcon equil = new ImageIcon("filepath/to/this/image");
ImageIcon escal = new ImageIcon("filepath/to/this/image");
ImageIcon isosc = new ImageIcon("filepath/to/this/image");
frame.add(label);
switch(t) {
        default: {
            label.setIcon(null);
        }

        case "Equilatero": {
            label.setIcon(equil);
        }

        case "Escaleno": {
            label.setIcon(escal);
        }

        case "Isosceles": {
            label.setIcon(isosc);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know how to create imageIcons for an image, all you need to do is add a JPanel to your frame and then add a JLabel to that. Then depending on the outcome of your string you set the icon of the jlabel to the corresponding image.

e.g.

```
//create panel and jlabel
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel();

//add the label to the panel, and the panel to the frame.
panel.add(label);
yourFrame.add(panel);

//Check what image you want
if(t.equals("Equilatero")){
    label.setIcon(example1Image);
else if(t.equals....
```